# How to use macros for hyperlink in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I have sharpoint site where I have uploaded the Excel.
I have few list each list have same excel hyper link..

What I want to perform..

In Excel I have some data, Onclick of first hyperlink I want to open same excel sheet but I want some row to be selected.

same I want when I click on other option it should open same excel but row should be different one slected.

I tried to acheive this using the Macros but not able kno, How i will configure for hperlink..

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Quick-start-Create-a-macro-455512ef-3532-404e-b8dd-ea6589512c1b

Comment: you need to provide more information such as how the workbook has been uploaded to sharepoint, in a document container, via the Excel Webpart ect..... Also an example of the list and link would be beneficial too.

Comment: That's what I am looking for.. How to upload that workbook or excel and how to use in hyperlink and say what I want to selected..

Comment: Can someone please guide me..